# optimizing an sql query using inner join and order by

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I'm trying to optimize the following query without success. Any idea where it could be indexed to prevent the temporary table and the filesort?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `groups`.*
FROM `groups`
INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `groups`.id = `memberships`.group_id
WHERE ((`memberships`.user_id = 1) 
  AND (`memberships`.`status_code` = 1 AND `memberships`.`manager` = 0))
ORDER BY groups.created_at DESC LIMIT 5;`

+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                                         | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | memberships | ref    | grp_usr,grp,usr,grp_mngr | usr     | 5       | const                                       |    5 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | groups      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | sportspool_development.memberships.group_id |    1 |                                              | 
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


    +--------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                          | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| groups |          0 | PRIMARY                           |            1 | id              | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| groups |          1 | index_groups_on_name              |            1 | name            | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| groups |          1 | index_groups_on_privacy_setting   |            1 | privacy_setting | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| groups |          1 | index_groups_on_created_at        |            1 | created_at      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| groups |          1 | index_groups_on_id_and_created_at |            1 | id              | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| groups |          1 | index_groups_on_id_and_created_at |            2 | created_at      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


     +-------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                                                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| memberships |          0 | PRIMARY                                                  |            1 | id          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          0 | grp_usr                                                  |            1 | group_id    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          0 | grp_usr                                                  |            2 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | grp                                                      |            1 | group_id    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | usr                                                      |            1 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | grp_mngr                                                 |            1 | group_id    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | grp_mngr                                                 |            2 | manager     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | complex_index                                            |            1 | group_id    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | complex_index                                            |            2 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | complex_index                                            |            3 | status_code | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | complex_index                                            |            4 | manager     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | index_memberships_on_user_id_and_status_code_and_manager |            1 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | index_memberships_on_user_id_and_status_code_and_manager |            2 | status_code | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| memberships |          1 | index_memberships_on_user_id_and_status_code_and_manager |            3 | manager     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+-------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: apologies for the horrible formatting. what to do to prevent that next time?

Comment: Indent 4 spaces - if you've got more than one line then select them and press the code button (the one with 0s and 1s on it)

Comment: How many rows does your membership table have? Also, how many rows would it use if you didn't have the "LIMIT 5" in the query?

Comment: When asking a question like this, it would be helpful to show the DDL for tables `groups` and `memberships`, so folks who answer know what indexes you currently have defined.

Answer (score 0):

- Index on `memberships` column `user_id` (should already have one if it's PK)
- Index on `memberships` columns `status_code` and  `manager`  (both of them on same index)
- Index on `groups` column `created_at` (with default DESC if possible, I don't know if you can in mySql)

This is what I would do in a MS SQL Server but I guess same optimization can be used in mySql too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the "obvious" single-column indexes on the fields you join on, the fields in your where clause and the created_at field you order by?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is you need an index on groups in order to eliminate the filesort, but all of your where conditions are on memberships.

Try adding an index on groups on (id, created_at).

If that doesn't work, try tricking the optimizer like so using a subquery (keeping the aforementioned index on groups):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `groups`.*
    FROM `groups`
    INNER JOIN (select group_id from `memberships`
       WHERE 
           `memberships`.user_id = 1
           AND `memberships`.`status_code` = 1
           AND `memberships`.`manager` = 0
    ) m on m.group_id=`groups`.id
    ORDER BY groups.created_at DESC LIMIT 5;
```

There should be an index on at least membershipships.user_id, but you could also gain some benefit from an index like (user_id, status, manager). I assume status and manager are flags that don't have a large range of possible values so it isn't that important as long as there's an index on user_id.

Comment: did you try that plus the query with the subquery that I suggested?

Comment: the sql with the subselect works much better however the query is generated dynamically (using Rails) and hard coding it would be ugly.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a way to do this using indexes alone; you need fine-tuned control over the sql in order to convince the query optimizer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A `(user_id, status_code, manager)` (in any order) index on `memberships` would help.

Avoiding the sort would be difficult, because then you have to start the join in the groups table, which means you can't use all the (presumably pretty selective) where clauses that reference the `memberships` table until it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting details about the indexes you're using.

I've tested this, and tried omitting some of the indexes.  The most index is `memberships.complex_index` which serves as a **covering index**.  This allows the query to achieve its results by reading only the index; it doesn't have to read data rows for `memberships` at all.

None of the indexes on `groups` make any difference.  It appears to use a filesort no matter what.  Filesort in MySQL simply means it's doing a table-scan, which in some cases can be *less costly* than using an index.  For instance, if every row of `groups` needs to be read to produce the result of the query anyway, why bother doing an unnecessary double-lookup by using an index?  The optimizer can sense these cases and can appropriately refuse to use an index.

So aside from primary key indexes and the `complex_index`, I'd drop all the others, since they're not helping and can only add to the cost of maintaining these tables.